# Capybara+rspec:Reset_Password routing error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, capybara, email-spec

So I am trying to test the simple feature of forgot password.I am newbie, so excuse me if its a silly question.
Here, I have to enter user email in forgot_password form which sends me a link in an email to reset password.
I am reaching inside the email, but when it clicks the link,page ends up on error page

[image]

```
 it "sends reset password email on submit",:js=> true, :focus=>true do


    visit "/login"
    click_link "Forgot Password?"
    sleep 1
    fill_in "email", :with => @user.email
    click_button "Submit"
    email = open_email(@user.email)
    email.should deliver_to(@user.email)
    #email.should have_subject("FlinkMusic - Forgot you password")
    click_first_link_in_email

    page.should have_content ("Reset your password")
        fill_in "Password ", :with => "password1" 
        fill_in "Repeat Password", :with => "password1"
        click_button "Reset Password"
        page.should have_content "Your password has been reset.Please log in."

end
```

here is my spec_helper

```
   require 'rubygems'
   require 'spork'
   Spork.prefork do

   ENV["RAILS_ENV"] ||= 'test'
   require File.expand_path("../../config/environment", __FILE__)
   require 'rspec/rails'
  require 'rspec/autorun'
  require 'capybara/rspec'
  require "capybara-screenshot"
  require 'factory_girl_rails'
  Dir[Rails.root.join("spec/support/**/*.rb")].each {|f| require f}

 #Capybara.defualt_wait_time = 10

  if ENV['BROWSER_TEST']
Capybara.register_driver :selenium do |app|
Capybara::Selenium::Driver.new(app, :browser => :chrome)
 end
else
Capybara.javascript_driver = :selenium
 end
RSpec.configure do |config|

      config.include Capybara::DSL

     config.include(EmailSpec::Helpers)
     config.include(EmailSpec::Matchers)


     config.treat_symbols_as_metadata_keys_with_true_values = true
     config.filter_run :focus => true
     config.run_all_when_everything_filtered = true
```

Is there anything I am missing it needs?
Thanks!

Comment: If I click on link manually, then everything works as expected.So the code I am trying to test works for sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was `click_first_link_in_email`. This was not clicking the real link.
I had to use `visit_in_email('Reset Password')` to make it open the Reset Password page.